# Images do not appear in Facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have written some code to share images on Facebook using Sharekit. The code is the following one:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00%d",currentIndex_+1];        
NSString *imageIndex = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:str ofType:@"png"];
NSLog(@"image index:%@",imageIndex);
// NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageIndex];

SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:[UIImage imageNamed:imageIndex] title:@"Sent via Card Application iPhone App"];
[NSClassFromString(@"SHKFacebook") performSelector:@selector(shareItem:) withObject:item];
```

The error message, "Required Upload Files" is shown.

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the following might help:

```
NSString *imageIndex = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:str ofType:@"png"];
```

Will return the path to the image.

```
[UIImage imageNamed:imageIndex]
```

Get an image from the applications bundle by it name.
You pass the path and name here, so it can't find the image.

Try this:

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:[UIImage imageNamed:str] title:@"Sent via Card Application iPhone App"];
[NSClassFromString(@"SHKFacebook") performSelector:@selector(shareItem:) withObject:item];
```